# How to show $2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{\frac{e^{e^{-1}}}{e^{-e^{-1}}}}+\sqrt{\frac{e^{-e^{-1}}}{e^{e^{-1}}}}\right)\right)^{2}<\pi$?

Tags: inequality, constants

### Problem :

### $$2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{\frac{e^{e^{-1}}}{e^{-e^{-1}}}}+\sqrt{\frac{e^{-e^{-1}}}{e^{e^{-1}}}}\right)\right)^{2}<\pi$$

Some related work :

You can find some material here [Showing $\sqrt{\frac{e}{2}}\cdot\frac{e}{\pi}\left(\frac{e}{2}-\frac{1}{e}\right)<1$ without a calculator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330847/showing-sqrt-frace2-cdot-frace-pi-left-frace2-frac1e-right) .

I also tried to play with :

$$\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\leq x+\frac{1}{x}$$

But it's really not satifactory .

As remark there is a link with the function $f(x)=x^x$ and the extrema .

In fact I found it in trying to show this problem [Prove that $\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^x}\, dx<2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585634/prove-that-int-0-infty-frac1xx-dx2?noredirect=1&lq=1) using [Reverse Cauchy Schwarz for integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879832/reverse-cauchy-schwarz-for-integrals?rq=1) .

---

---

Edit :

We an interesting inequality here [How can you show by hand that $ e^{-1/e} < \ln(2) $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338415/how-can-you-show-by-hand-that-e-1-e-ln2)

---

---

How to show it without a calculator ?

---

---

Thanks and Im quite excited by your answer .

Comment: $$2+\frac{1}{4}\left(\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\right)^2=\frac52+\frac14\left(x+\frac1x\right)$$

Comment: Where $x=e^{2e^{-1}}$

Comment: $$\frac{e^y}{e^{-y}}=e^{2y}.$$ So this can be rewritten as $$2+\cosh^2(e^{-1}).$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for your comment .