# Show that $2\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}}\right)<e^{-1}+1$ by hand .

Tags: inequality

Problem :

Show that :

$$2\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}}\right)<e^{-1}+1$$

I have tried a similar approach to the accepted answer here [Showing $\sqrt{\frac{e}{2}}\cdot\frac{e}{\pi}\left(\frac{e}{2}-\frac{1}{e}\right)<1$ without a calculator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330847/showing-sqrt-frace2-cdot-frace-pi-left-frace2-frac1e-right) as attempt without success .

Taking the exponential on the two side we have a similar question here [How can you show by hand that $ e^{-1/e} < \ln(2) $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338415/how-can-you-show-by-hand-that-e-1-e-ln2)

Using an inequality due to user Michael Rozenberg ([Which is greater $\frac{13}{32}$ or $\ln \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713384/which-is-greater-frac1332-or-ln-left-frac32-right?noredirect=1&lq=1)) we have :

$$\ln\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)<8\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}-1\right)\left(\frac{2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}<e^{-1}+1$$

Where we have for $x\geq 1 $ :

$$\ln\left(x\right)-\left(x-1\right)\left(\frac{2}{x^{2}+x}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\leq 0$$

But it seems too difficult .

Question :

How to show it properly by hand ?

Comment: Please stop finishing all your questions with a (triple indented) “Thanks in advance“, this is considered “unnecessary clutter” – compare https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21039/42969 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/196432.

Comment: @MartinR oh well I understand .

Comment: The left-hand side is equal to $\ln(5 \pi/4)$, is there a reason to write it in that obfuscated way?

Comment: @MartinR there is the golden ratio .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general algorithm to solve these sorts of problems is to expand each side as an infinite series, and the compute enough terms that the difference between values is smaller than the omitted terms.

Good formulas for $\pi$ are difficult to prove, and so usually do not appear in introductory courses.  The best technique (IMHO) is the first few terms in the continued fraction expansion of $\pi$: $$3<\frac{333}{106}<\pi<\frac{355}{113}<\frac{22}{7} \tag{1}$$  To verify these yourself, pick your favorite series or physical experiment to determine $\pi$ and compute until you have enough digits to apply the Babylonian algorithm for continued fractions; the convergents necessarily bound $\pi$ from either side.

On the other hand, the standard series defining $e$ is already very good.  So our goal is going to try to manipulate the expression so that we have something that depends only slowly on $\pi$, but might be sensitive to $e$.

First, simplify: $$2\ln{\!\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}}\right)}=\ln{\!\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)}$$  Now exponentiate and multiply by $4/5$; we want to show $$\pi<\frac{4}{5}e^{1+\frac{1}{e}}$$  Well, \begin{align*}
\frac{4}{5}e^{1+\frac{1}{e}}&=4e\cdot\exp{(e^{-1})} \\
&=\frac{4}{5}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-k}}{k!}} \\
&=\frac{4}{5}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-k)^j}{j!}}} \\
&>\frac{4}{5}\left(\sum_{k=0}^K{\frac{1}{k!}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^K{\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{2\left\lfloor\frac{K^2}{4}\right\rfloor+1}{\frac{(-k)^j}{j!}}} \tag{2}
\end{align*} where $K$ is an arbitrary cutoff.  (The cutoff for $j$ probably seems a bit mysterious.  It needs to be an odd index so that we have an underestimate, and the general rule of thumb is that an outer power series should have a cutoff that is "little-o" of the inner cutoff.)

Now, compute out (2) until it is larger than a continued fraction on the RHS of (1).  As it turns out, the first few terms of (2) are $$\frac{4}{5},\frac{8}{5},\frac{7}{3},\frac{124}{45},\frac{20\,288\,671}{6\,531\,840},\frac{338\,258\,747\,357}{107\,775\,360\,000},\frac{1\,086\,051\,649\,968\,809\,811\,589}{345\,728\,180\,109\,312\,000\,000},\frac{368\,396\,503\,404\,331\,527\,428\,943\,031\,481}{117\,264\,747\,927\,582\,254\,039\,040\,000\,000},\frac{138\,588\,995\,483\,500\,733\,892\,865\,856\,936\,548\,310\,244\,500\,953}{44\,114\,032\,165\,202\,403\,200\,910\,993\,380\,710\,809\,600\,000\,000},\dots$$  I cheated and used *Mathematica* to compute these fractions.  But you *could* do this by hand — it's just tedious.

In any case, the last fraction I listed above is greater than $\frac{355}{113}$.  So

Thus \begin{align*}
\frac{4}{5}e^{1+\frac{1}{e}}&>\frac{4}{5}\left(\sum_{k=0}^8{\frac{1}{k!}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^8{\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{33}{\frac{(-k)^j}{j!}}} \\
&=\frac{138\,588\,995\,483\,500\,733\,892\,865\,856\,936\,548\,310\,244\,500\,953}{44\,114\,032\,165\,202\,403\,200\,910\,993\,380\,710\,809\,600\,000\,000} \\
&>\frac{355}{133} \\
&>\pi
\end{align*}